# How do I reverse text in C#?

Tags: c#, string, reverse

I know this is a simple question, but I thought I'd give it a try.

So say I have a TextBox named "toReverse". If I wanted to reverse all the text in that TextBox, how would I go about doing that?

Also, I can't use VB.NET in it, even though it has a one-line way of doing it.

Comment: Uh, have you looked at the Microsoft documentation for .Net "string"???  As an "Array.Reverse(string.toCharArray())"?

Comment: I (thought) I implied that I didn't want to do it in one line. Reading through it again, I realized I didn't do a very good job of that, sorry.

Comment: @Minicl55 Why can't you do it in one line? That seems like a weird requirement. You could just start putting in random like breaks.

Comment: Minicl55, your odd requirements make it appear like you're asking us to do your homework, but are trying to hide that fact (this is a common first-semester programming assignment).

Comment: Michael, I got out of school three days ago. Who would be assigning me  a project?

Comment: That's a good question. You still haven't answered vcjones question.

Comment: If this isn't homework, why can't you do it in one line? Who/what is preventing you from doing it that way?

Comment: I "assigned" it to myself. I couldn't get it, so I figured that I might as well figure out how to do it.

Comment: `I got out of school three days ago` And you can't reverse a string. Which school is this?

Comment: `I figured that I might as well figure out how to do it` by coming here and marking the worst answer as the solution? I googled the title of your question and found 4.3Million links

Comment: Ok if the answer is worst then moderator can delete it, any body can make a request i dont want to be the worst one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
char[] chararray = this.toReverse.Text.ToCharArray();
Array.Reverse(chararray);
string reverseTxt = "";
for (int i = 0; i <= chararray.Length - 1; i++)
{
    reverseTxt += chararray.GetValue(i);
}
this.toReverse.Text = reverseTxt;
```

Hope this helps

[image: Demo Image]

Comment: But if you're going to use `Array.Reverse` anyway, why not do the one-liner?

Comment: @JimMischel Answer i provided keeping the basics in my mind. I am a learner my self, so what i know i will provide answer according to that. no problem doing in one liner. Every day i learn and improve at the end of that day guru like you always here to improve the way a person like me think and do code.

Comment: @Minicl55 see my answer and double check this is going to work.

Comment: selbarésiM seL  this is the answer.

Answer (score 17):

```
using System.Linq;

new String(str.Reverse().ToArray());
```

Answer (score 5):

You can pass it to Array of char and reverse it :)

```
char[] arr = s.ToCharArray();
Array.Reverse(arr);
var yourString = new string(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you could go about doing this if you don't want to use the built-in facilities. For example, you could create an array, reverse the array (with an explicit loop rather than `Array.Reverse`), and then create a new string from the array:

```
char[] txt = myString.ToArray();
int i = 0;
int j = txt.Length - 1;
while (i < j)
{
    char t = txt[i];
    txt[i] = txt[j];
    txt[j] = t;
    ++i;
    --j;
}
string reversed = new string(txt);
```

Another way is to use a stack. Push the individual characters on the stack, then pop them off to populate a `StringBuilder`:

```
Stack<char> charStack = new Stack<char>();
foreach (var c in myString)
{
    charStack.Push(c);
}
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(myString.Length);
while (charStack.Count > 0)
{
    sb.Append(charStack.Pop());
}
string reversed = sb.ToString();
```

Another way would be to walk through the string backwards, populating a `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(myString.Length);
for (int i = myString.Length-1; i >= 0; --i)
{
    sb.Append(myString[i]);
}
string reversed = sb.ToString();
```

And of course there are many variations to the above.